# Firestore error - INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown wrong type: symbol

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I develop web app with React which use firestore.

I try to create new document with data provided as js object:

```
this.props.firestore.add({collection: 'sample'}, data)
        .then((docRef) => {...}
```

sometimes it works without any problem but in about 50% of tests I get an firebase error:
"FIRESTORE (5.5.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown wrong type: symbol"

I use these extensions to handle firestore:

`"redux-firestore": "^0.5.8"
"react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.6"
"firebase": "^5.8.4"`

Thanks for any help in solving this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly solve the problem by making a deep copy of my data object with:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I have no idea what is wrong with the original one. :(

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search showed that firebase is on 5.17.0 and there have been multiple fixes related to symbol collisions since 5.5.0

Comment: Which firebase do you think about?
It's firebase javascript API with newest version 5.8.4 [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)
Unfortunetly update has not solve the problem :(